# FortiClient VPN in KUbuntu 22.04 with SSO gets stuck in "Connecting..."

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, forticlient

I'm facing issues while trying to set up FortiClient VPN on KUbuntu 22.04. The installation goes smoothly after manually adding a dependency package. However, when I attempt to connect using Single Sign On (SSO), the authentication window briefly opens and closes, leaving me stuck on the "Connecting..." stage. This is the window where I should enter my username and password and then use a 2FA app for verification.

Even after enabling "Use external browser as user-agent for saml user authentication," the problem persists. The same behavior occurs, and an external browser doesn't open as expected.

I had no trouble with this kind of connection on Kubuntu 20.04. Has anyone managed to successfully establish this type of connection on (K)Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Have you tried the support forum? https://community.fortinet.com/t5/forums/filteredbylabelpage/board-id/fortinet-discussion/label-name/forticlient?pageNum=2

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

Install the gpg key:

```
wget -O - https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/forticlient/7.2/debian/DEB-GPG-KEY | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/repo.fortinet.com.gpg
```

Create **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo.fortinet.com.list** with the following content:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/repo.fortinet.com.gpg] https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/forticlient/7.2/debian/ stable non-free
```

Update package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install FortiClient:

```
sudo apt install forticlient
```

https://docs.fortinet.com/document/forticlient/7.2.1/linux-release-notes/213138/install-forticlient-linux-from-repo-fortinet-com

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmAkV.png)